# Android xml nullpointer exception xml parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

I'm using the sax xmlparser and I am unable to print results through toast. I get a null pointer exception. I found an example that uses textview array but I want to use toast. The original code from android people works fine, but if I apply the same code in my own project it fails everytime.

Main.java >

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

String strGK = null;
String strHWW = null;
String strHak5 = null;

    CheckBox GK;
    CheckBox HWW;
    CheckBox Hak5;

    SitesList sitesList = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void getUrl(View v) {
        try {
            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
            URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://websitethatcontains/feed");

            /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
        }

        /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

        /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) { /** <- the prob. seems to be here */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sitesList.getName().get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void getUrl(View v) {
    MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler;
    try {
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL("http://websitethatcontains/feed");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Exception = " + e);
    }

    if (MyXMLHandler != null){
        /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

        /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) { /** <- the prob. seems to be here */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sitesList.getName().get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not do the trick. The goal or purpose of this code is that I want to gather links from an rss feed and put them in an array. Like this one: http://tweakers.mobi/rss/nieuws

Comment: The link from the original code is here: http://www.androidpeople.com/xml-parsing